# I need help by returning a new tuple by concatenation the provided tuple with another element (123)?

Tags: python

For example:

```
add_more_tup((1, 2, 3)) --> (1, 2, 3, 123)
add_more_tup(()) --> (123)
```

this is what i have but it gives me an error when submitting

```
def add_more_tup(my_tup):
  my_tup = (1, 2, 3), + (123)# Return a tuple here.
  return my_tup
```

Comment: You should have `return my_tup + (123,)`

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want to do? Add a new element to the tuple? If yes then try: my_tup = (1,2,3) + (123,). Please notice the comma after 123.

Answer (score 1):

For more generic case you want something like this

```
>>> def add_more_tup(my_tup):
...     if not my_tup:
...         return ()
...     return my_tup + (int("".join(map(lambda e: str(e), my_tup))), )
...
>>> print add_more_tup((1,2,3))
(1, 2, 3, 123)
>>> print add_more_tup(())
()
```

`int("".join(map(lambda e: str(e), my_tup))` does couple of things:

1. It converts an int tuple to list of strings with `map(lambda e:
   str(e), my_tup)`.
2. Joins the resulting list in one string with `"".join(...)`
3. Converts it to int with `int(...)`

Appending the tuple is the same as suggested in comments, 
`return my_tup + (new_element,)`. In general, I would recommend using lists rather than tuples, since tuples are not really meant to be extended (change length).

Answer (score 0):

You had a random comma in between (1,2,3) and +. This should do.

```
def add_more_tup(my_tup):
    my_tup = (1, 2, 3) + (123,)# Return a tuple here.
    return my_tup
```

Edit: Comma after single integer in tuple (Thanks zondo)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary comma in your assignment statement.
Your function should be as follows:

```
def add_more_tup(my_tup):
   return my_tup + (123,)
```

Examples:

```
In [148]: add_more_tup((4,5,6))
Out[148]: (4, 5, 6, 123)

In [149]: add_more_tup((1,2,3))
Out[149]: (1, 2, 3, 123)
```